# Use `%^{prop}p` `%^{prompt}` together in org-capture-templates

Tags: org-mode, template

What I want is when the buffer asks me  a value for property , I can also  replace property name with some alternatives.

I tried the following code, but fails

```
(setq org-capture-templates
      '(("R" "Reference" entry (file+datetree "~/Dropbox/org/reference.org")
         "* %? (one sentence each
part)\n%^{^{Conclusion|default|come1}}p%^{Detail}p%^{Reason}p%^{Good_for_me}p\nEntered on %U\n %i\n" :prepend t
:kill-buffer t)
        )
      )
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't do this with the t`%^` template format strings.  You can however call `org-set-property` when your template is constructed using the `%(func)` syntax.  When called interactively `org-set-property` prompts for both the property and the value.  Here's a simple example:

```
(setq org-capture-templates
  '(("P" "Property" entry
     "* %? %(call-interactively #'org-set-property)"))
```